# Redirect to previous url after logout

Tags: java, security, playframework

On `login`, a user can be redirected to the page that requested login using the `url` value set in `flash`.

Is is possible to have the same use case, redirect the user to the page that requested the logout action after logout?

Comment: You have pages which request logout? Well, as you said, have those pages add an url-parameter to the request, `?page=/somepage.html)`, and use that for a redirect.

Comment: Also you can store that url in cookies, through flash-javascipt bridge.

Comment: What are using for login/logout? You own custom actions or are you using the secure module?

Comment: Why not use the referrer value in headers? X page contains logout link, click the link the reference came from X page so once the logout is done you can redirect to referrer, is that what you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thank you all for the comments on the question, going with `Johan Sjöberg`'s suggestions, even `stackoverflow` is using it ;-), check the logout link.

On the template

```
<a href="@{Secure.logout2(request.url)}">logout</a>
```

In `Secure.java` i added `logout2`

```
public static void logout2(String returnUrl) throws Throwable {
    flash.put("returnUrl", returnUrl == null ? "/" : returnUrl);
    logout();
}
```

and modified `logout`

```
public static void logout() throws Throwable {
    session.clear();
    response.removeCookie("rememberme");
    Security.invoke("onDisconnected");
    flash.success(Messages.get("secure.logout", "You have been successfully logged out"));

    String returnUrl = flash.get("returnUrl");
    redirect(returnUrl == null ? "/" : returnUrl);
}
```

Comment: I'm brand-spanking-new to the Play! framework (but absolutely loving it!) so maybe I'm off-base here but isn't it usually considered bad-practice to directly modify a framework's class???  I would have expected a solution that overrides a particular feature of a framework's class. For example, what happens when play#secure-module gets an upgrade that you want?  You're going to have to make sure you police your code.  See my solution for how I solved this problem.

Answer (score 8):

(Just elucidating allenskd's comment)

A lot depends on how your logout is implemented, but if it's just a controller or a jsp, you don't have to pass the url to it. You can use the referer header.

```
String refererUrl = request.getHeader("referer")
```

Answer (score 2):

Having found the other answers here unacceptable (or just didn't quite fit my approach) I pinged-away until I came up with something I like better.  Here's what I did:

```
public class Security extends Secure.Security {

    /* Overrides the same method from Secure.Security.
     * I only needed to redirect back the home-page so I just
     * hard-coded the redirect-url here; but you could also have
     * directed your logout-link to #logout2(String url) where you do a
     * flash#put() and then here do a flash#get() and redirect to
     * to that url instead (see n002213f's answer for more detail; 
     * but I thought it bad-practice to do the other half of his 
     * answer -- directly modifying the #logout() method of the
     * play#secure-module)
    static void onDisconnected() {
        redirect( "/" );
    }

}


index.html:
    (...) <a href="logout">Logout</a> (...)
```

So what happens here is that the default play#secure#logout() is called and at the end of the logout-process it fires Secure#Security#onDisconnected -- which is overridden and redirects to the home-page.  This way play's own built-in security isn't being bypassed so you're not risking breaking your security, you also aren't directly modifying the play#secure-module code which means when it's updated you won't find yourself in a pickle, and yet you are achieving your result: not being redirected to the default play#secure-login page, but instead going straight back to the homepage.

If anyone more seasoned with Play! than I see a problem with this (or if my criticism of the other solutions is unfounded) I'd love to hear back!

Otherwise I think this is the most elegant and simplest way to achieve the goal.